# Why was AMS-02 launched to the ISS instead on being standalone?

Tags: iss

I understand launching the module to the ISS has several benefits:

1. Power supply is provided
2. Servicing capacity
3. Orbital control is provided
4. Thermal control might be provided ?

But what are the key factors that made it a module instead of a simple satellite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer) article on the AMS:

> The power requirements for AMS-02 were thought to be too great for a practical independent spacecraft.

The AMS needs up to 2.5 kW, so as an independent satellite it would need rather large solar panels.